# Javascript click event ClientX and clientY value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(function() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("button1");
  x[0].value = "This is done by my code";
  x[0].onclick = function() {
    alert('clicked');
    alert(event.clientX + ' ' + event.clientY)
  }
  x[0].click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" class="button1" value="Send" >
```

Above is my code. Issue which I get here is, I am not getting clientX and ClienY both the values as 0, since button is clicked through my code.

Can I change ClientX and clientY value to some number through my code?

or

Can I generate mouse click event such that it can return some positive number in ClientX and ClientY?

Comment: What do you expect these values to be? It doesn't make sense to try and get the mouse position of an event not triggered by a mouse? What re you trying to do here?

Comment: As I am aware of, those are read only variables. Why don't you just create some new variables and  give them any positive number? Afterwards you can do anything you want with them as you would do with clientX/Y. I think you don't need to edit `clientX` or `clientY`.